# Entity Framework taking a lot of time initializing model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm facing an issue with EF taking a lot of time (spanning hours) to initialize models. The model is as given below. There are around 20 classes which are derived from A1, and about 30 classes which derive from A2.

[image]

I had to move from TPT to TPH strategy to [fix an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171506/out-of-memory-exception-while-retrieving-a-lazy-loaded-list-in-entity-framewor) related to memory usage. And since then I'm trying to figure out this issue.

The issue is produced by just creating a single instance of type 'A', adding it to a `List<A>` property of another entity and committing those changes. At this moment, it has already taken about 2.5 hours, and still hasn't committed the changes yet!

Breaking into the code (after waiting for about an hour to finish), the call stack is:

```
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.IfThenElse(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex condition, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex then, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex else) + 0x14e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.And.AnonymousMethod__1(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex left, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex right) + 0x29 bytes 
System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex,System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex> source, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex seed, System.Func<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex,System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex,System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex> func) + 0x99 bytes 
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Solver.And(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Vertex> children) + 0x90 bytes   
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.ToDecisionDiagramConverter<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.DomainConstraint<System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.BoolLiteral,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.Constant>>.VisitAnd(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.AndExpr<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.DomainConstraint<System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.BoolLiteral,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.Constant>> expression) + 0x77 bytes 
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.AndExpr<System.__Canon>.Accept<System.__Canon>(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Visitor<System.__Canon,System.__Canon> visitor) + 0xc bytes 
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.ToDecisionDiagramConverter<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.DomainConstraint<System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.BoolLiteral,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.Constant>>.TranslateToRobdd(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.BoolExpr<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.DomainConstraint<System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.BoolLiteral,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.Constant>> expr, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.ConversionContext<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.DomainConstraint<System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.BoolLiteral,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.Constant>> context) + 0x72 bytes 
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.Converter<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.DomainConstraint<System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.BoolLiteral,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.Constant>>.Converter(System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.BoolExpr<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.DomainConstraint<System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.BoolLiteral,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.Constant>> expr, System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.ConversionContext<System.Data.Common.Utils.Boolean.DomainConstraint<System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.BoolLiteral,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.Constant>> context) + 0x46 bytes 
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryProcessor.IsSatisfiable(System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.BoolExpression condition) + 0xac bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryProcessor.IsSatisfiable(System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQuery query) + 0x8 bytes    
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CellTreeNode.IsEmptyRightFragmentQuery.get() + 0x1e bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.BasicViewGenerator.IsDisjoint(System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CellTreeNode n1, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CellTreeNode n2) + 0xbb bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.BasicViewGenerator.TryAddChildToGroup(System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CellTreeOpType opTypeToIsolate, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CellTreeNode childNode, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.OpCellTreeNode groupNode) + 0x3f bytes    
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.BasicViewGenerator.IsolateByOperator(System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CellTreeNode rootNode, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CellTreeOpType opTypeToIsolate) + 0x1eb bytes 
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.BasicViewGenerator.CreateViewExpression() + 0xeb bytes    
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.QueryRewriter.GenerateViewComponents() + 0x12a bytes   
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateViewsForExtentAndType(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmType generatedType, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenContext context, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CqlIdentifiers identifiers, System.Data.Common.Utils.KeyToListMap<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView> views, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenMode mode) + 0x2f bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateDirectionalViewsForExtent(System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.ViewTarget viewTarget, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase extent, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CqlIdentifiers identifiers, System.Data.Common.Utils.KeyToListMap<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView> views) + 0x58 bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateDirectionalViews(System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.ViewTarget viewTarget, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CqlIdentifiers identifiers, System.Data.Common.Utils.KeyToListMap<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView> views) + 0xce bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateAllBidirectionalViews(System.Data.Common.Utils.KeyToListMap<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView> views, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CqlIdentifiers identifiers) + 0xd7 bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenGatekeeper.GenerateViewsFromCells(System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.Cell> cells, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ConfigViewGenerator config, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.CqlIdentifiers identifiers, System.Data.Mapping.StorageEntityContainerMapping containerMapping) + 0x1aa bytes    
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenGatekeeper.GenerateViewsFromMapping(System.Data.Mapping.StorageEntityContainerMapping containerMapping, System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ConfigViewGenerator config) + 0xbf bytes    
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGenerateViews(System.Data.Mapping.StorageEntityContainerMapping entityContainerMap, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView> resultDictionary) + 0x3a bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGetGeneratedViews(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityContainer container) + 0xd2 bytes 
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>.Evaluate.AnonymousMethod__0() + 0x13 bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityContainer,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView>>.Result.GetValue() + 0x69 bytes    
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityContainer,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase,System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.GeneratedView>>.Evaluate(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntityContainer arg) + 0x6e bytes   
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase extent, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace workspace, System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection) + 0x49 bytes    
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.ViewLoader.InitializeEntitySet(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase entitySetBase, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace workspace) + 0x74 bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.ViewLoader.SyncInitializeEntitySet<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase entitySetBase, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace workspace, System.Func<System.__Canon,System.__Canon> evaluate, System.__Canon arg) + 0xdf bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.ViewLoader.SyncGetValue<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssociationSet,System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.AssociationSetMetadata>(System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EntitySetBase entitySetBase, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace workspace, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssociationSet,System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.AssociationSetMetadata> dictionary, System.Data.Metadata.Edm.AssociationSet key) + 0x9c bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ValidateAndRegisterStateEntry(System.Data.IEntityStateEntry stateEntry) + 0x109 bytes   
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.LoadStateEntry(System.Data.IEntityStateEntry stateEntry) + 0x23 bytes   
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.PullModifiedEntriesFromStateManager() + 0x156 bytes 
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands() + 0x1a bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(System.Data.IEntityStateManager stateManager, System.Data.IEntityAdapter adapter) + 0xc9 bytes   
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(System.Data.IEntityStateManager entityCache) + 0x93 bytes  
System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions options) + 0x23c bytes 
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() + 0x144 bytes 
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() + 0x36 bytes  
EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() + 0x35 bytes
```

Comment: Can you use profiler to see which methods in model generation cause the issue? If not can you share your model?

Answer (score 2):

From the stacktrace you showed it appears to me that the problem is in View Generation. Since you are using code first I would encourage you to try [EF6](http://entityframework.codeplex.com) which contains performance improvements for view generation. For previous versions as a workaround you can pre-generate views (e.g. using EF Power Tools or a template I created http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ae7730ce-ddab-470f-8456-1b313cd2c44d). It will still take long to create the view but it will be at design time and not runtime.

Comment: I gave EF6 Alpha 2 a try, and still the performance seems to be the same! It's taking too much time to get those views generated; I still haven't been able to execute the application past the view generation phase.

Comment: Can you share your model with me?

Comment: Is it normal for view generation to take that much time (spanning multiple hours)? From what I read around, people generally complain about view generation taking minutes.

Comment: It depends on the model. I would not say it is normal for view generation to take hours but we have seen models for which it would be the case. I would also say minutes is already too long. If you can share your model I would pass it the some people that looked at view gen improvements for EF6 and they may be able to either find things to improve or maybe recommend changes to your model to improve view gen time.

Comment: Would a generated EDMX suffice for analysis or do you need the entire model and mapping source code? I'm sorry but I not sure whether I would be able to share the source code.

Comment: I think edmx should be enough.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22798/discussion-between-trainee4life-and-pawel)